# 1D Infinite Square Box Discrete Energy levels but Continous Momenta?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, potential, discrete

In the 1d particle in the box the energy of the particle should be completely determined by the momentum of the particle that you observe correct? So how can you have discrete energy levels and a continuous momentum spectrum at the same time?

Comment: This potential doesn't allow a continuous momentum spectrum.

Comment: *"energy of the particle should be completely determined by the momentum of the particle that you observe correct?"* Only in classical theory - energy is $(momentum)^2/2m$. In quantum theory, we cannot determine momentum of the particle so easily - any measurement will probably change its state significantly. Instead of definite value of momentum, we use wave function $\psi$. For any normalized $\psi$,  many different position and momentum values are possible, $\psi$ determining their probability density.  This does not mean that momentum operator $i\hbar d/dx$ has continuous spectrum.

Comment: Surely there is a momentum uncertainty given roughly by $2\Delta x/\hbar$ around a momentum with an expectation value of zero ?

Comment: The comment by @AlfredCentauri should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The momentum operator $P$ in the infinite well can be defined as a self-adjoint operator by infinitely many ways with respect to the boundary conditions by:
$$P_\theta=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\\
\mathcal{D}(P_\theta)=\left\{\psi\in \mathcal{H}^1[0,a]:\psi(a)=e^{i\theta}\psi(0)\right\},$$
where $\mathcal{H}^1[0,a]$ is the [Sobolev space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space), on the interval $[0,a]$. In any case, the spectrum is purely discrete, which can be seen by solving the eigenvalue equation
$$P_\theta\psi_n=\lambda_{\theta,n}\psi_n$$
The equation yields the eigenvalues
$$\lambda_{\theta,n}=\frac{2\pi\hbar}{a}\left(n+\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right), \qquad n\in\Bbb{Z},$$
with eigenfunctions
$$\psi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\exp\left(\frac{i\lambda_{\theta,n}x}{\hbar}\right),$$
which constitutes a basis for the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=L^2[0,a]$.

**Edit:** concerning the comments, viewing the infinite well as a limiting procedure of finite well leads to boundary conditions on the Hamiltonian to be given by:
$$H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\\
\mathcal{D}(H)=\left\{\psi \in \mathcal{H}^2[0,a]:\psi(0)=\psi(a)=0\right\},$$
so, although the action of $H$ seems to give the idea that the momentum eigenfunctions are also energy eigenfunctions, this is false, because the action is not defined, since the functions are not in $\mathcal{D}(H)$.

Using boundary conditions such that $\psi(0)=\psi(a)=0$ for the moimentum operator **does not give a self-adjoint operator**, since the adjoint $P^*$ has a bigger domain, in this case $\mathcal{D}(P^*)=\mathcal{H}^1[0,a]$. As observables must be represented by **self-adjoint** and not just symmetric operators, this boundary condition is not valid. Check [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103153) article for a better discussion.

Comment: Ok cool. Is Griffiths wrong then? The probability distribution in momentum space doesn't seem discrete to me http://physicspages.com/2012/10/04/infinite-square-well-momentum-space-wave-functions/.

Comment: In a certain way, he is wrong. Calling the Fourier transform $\Phi_n(p,t)$ of the wavefunction $\psi_n(x,t)$ as the momentum representation is not quite right, because this representation is only valid if the space is $L^2(\Bbb{R})$. What he does is to consider the domain of $\psi_n(x,t)$ as the whole real line, but with support only on $[0,a]$.

Comment: What is your $\theta$, can $\theta$ be zero?

Comment: $\theta$ is any real number, but of course, it can be considered only in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, because $e^{i\theta}$ is periodic. Setting $\theta=0$ is to give periodic boundary conditions, since it would imply $\psi(a)=\psi(0)$.

Comment: In your answer, the eigenstates of momentum operator seems also the eigenstates of Hamitonian. It is strange for me, since these two operators are not commutative, they should not share the same set of eigenstates.

Comment: Write Hamiltonian in this way:$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V\theta(-x)+V\theta(x-a)\quad V\rightarrow+\infty$$

Since the explicit dependence of $x$ in potential, so $[H,p]\neq0$.

Comment: @MateusSampaio, what you write is mathematically correct, but physically misleading. In physics, infinite potential wells are limits of finite ones. In the limit $V\rightarrow\infty$ the Schroedinger equation and the condition of normalizability of $\psi$ leads to boundary condition $\psi(0)=0$, not $|\psi(0)|>0$, so in this limit the operator $i\hbar \,d/dx$ has no eigenfunctions.

Comment: Made an edit, concerning the comments.

Comment: @MateusSampaio While your answer is too mathematical for me, I think your point is "the action is not defined". Basically it is a no way to solve the eigenvalue equation for both operators in the same space.

Comment: It's important to note that these distinctions are not trivial and not limited to quantum physics. A good resource is [Classical symptoms of quantum illnesses](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.17221) by C. Zhu and J.R. Klauder.

Answer (score 2):

> In the 1d particle in the box the energy of the particle should be
>   completely determined by the momentum of the particle that you observe
>   correct?

The Hamiltonian in the position basis is

$$\hat H = \begin{cases}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}, & 0\lt x \lt a\\\infty, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

and the energy eigenfunctions are of the form

$$\psi_n(x,t) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x \right)\left[\theta(x) -  \theta(x - a)\right]e^{-i\omega_nt}$$

which are clearly *not* momentum eigenfunctions.  So, no, the quoted statement is not correct.

> So how can you have discrete energy levels and a continuous momentum
>   spectrum at the same time?

This potential doesn't allow a continuous momentum spectrum.

It *is* true that we can find the continuous $\phi_n(p,t)$ and expand $\psi_n(x,t)$ over the momentum eigenfunctions.

However, thinking clearly about this, the energy eigenfunctions are only complete on the interval $[0,a]$.  That is to say, we cannot expand a momentum eigenfunction over the energy eigenfunctions.

Put another way, the operator $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ has no eigenfunctions for this potential.

Comment: So from the answers I'm getting then, you can't measure the momentum? This would apply to any potential where there are regions where the particle acts like a free particle but with discrete energy like the finite square well.  What I don't get is then is, physically speaking how exactly would you then measure the energy of the particle?

Comment: @CrazyDolphin, I'm working up an addition to my answer that will look at this in the limit of the finite potential well.  I suspect that, as the well becomes deeper, the expectation of the energy increases without bound for a momentum eigenstate.